# SQL select query almost works, except for the ORDER BY

Tags: query

I've got a query that very nearly works, except for the ORDER BY part.

In Plain English, I'm selecting the author_ids for authors who've posted entries to a particular channel, and limiting it by a few member groups.

(why is this a query? Will use this as basis to list entries in channel by member, limiting the number of entries/author to 4)

So far, so good. This Query works:

```
 {exp:query sql="SELECT DISTINCT author_id 
    FROM exp_channel_titles 
    JOIN exp_members ON exp_channel_titles.author_id = exp_members.member_id 
    WHERE exp_channel_titles.channel_id='5' 
    AND exp_channel_titles.status = 'open'
    AND (exp_members.group_id = '5' OR exp_members.group_id = '6' OR exp_members.group_id = '7' OR exp_members.group_id = '8')"}
```

It works, but the listing needs to be ordered differently. I want to order them alphabetically by member last name.

Am using Profile:Edit and have custom channel fields for member_first_name and member_last_name (field_id_50)

I need to refer to exp_channel_titles twice. Here's a graphic representation of what info I'm referring to in the database:

```
 ct  exp_channel_titles             exp_members
     ==================             ===========
     author_id                      member_id
     status = open                  group_id = 5|6|7|8
     channel_id = 5

 ct2 exp_channel_titles             exp_channel_data
     ==================             ================
     entry_id                       entry_id
     channel_id = 12                field_id_50
     author_id
```

Here's my second query. It doesn't throw errors (um, yay?), but it does not change the order of the results, either.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ct.author_id
FROM exp_channel_titles AS ct 
JOIN exp_channel_titles AS ct2 ON ct.author_id = ct2.author_id
JOIN exp_members ON ct.author_id = exp_members.member_id
JOIN exp_channel_data ON exp_channel_data.entry_id = ct2.author_id
WHERE ct.channel_id = 5
AND ct.status = 'open'
AND ct2.channel_id = 12
AND (exp_members.group_id = 5 OR exp_members.group_id = 6 OR exp_members.group_id = 7 OR exp_members.group_id = 8)
ORDER BY exp_channel_data.field_id_50 ASC
```

changing the first line does not produces an empty column of results for last name 
        SELECT DISTINCT ct.author_id, exp_channel_data.field_id_50
        FROM etc.

How do I get my ORDER BY to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, this line is incorrect...Entry_id <> author_id

`JOIN exp_channel_data ON exp_channel_data.entry_id = ct2.author_id`

Take your query and paste it into the [inbuilt query form](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/tools/data/sql_query_form.html).
Remove or add query lines one by one and test your query output until you get what you want.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out where I erred. I changed that line to this: `JOIN exp_channel_data ON exp_channel_data.entry_id = ct2.entry_id` and tested results in Sequel Pro. Good. In template, it works!